# MySQL automatic insert data, count between two date in different column

Tags: mysql

I'm new in sql.
Now I want to count days between two date in different column (TGL_PEMINJAMAN and TGL_PENGEMBALIAN), and automatic insert on another column (SISA_HARI)

TGL_PEMINJAMAN -> date

TGL_PENGEMBALIAN -> date

SISA_HARI -> int

[Here's screenshoot my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr90l.png)

**for example** in ID_PEMINJAMAN = 3

**TGL_PEMINJAMAN -> 2017-07-02**

**TGL_PENGEMBALIAN -> 2017-07-07**

**and in SISA_HARI must be automatic insert -> 5**

So, what should I do? May I try to use trigger on sql?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the difference between the two dates **TGL_PEMINJAMAN**  and **TGL_PENGEMBALIAN** as a selection, you may try this sql

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TGL_PEMINJAMAN,'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(TGL_PENGEMBALIAN,'DD-MM-YYYY') as Datediff FROM YOURTABLENAME;
```

You are right, If it must be automatically updated and your MYSQL version is compatible, you can try with [trigger](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/mysql-triggers.html).